# Finding SubSystems in a Simulink model using find_system() instruction in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to find all the SubSystems present in a Simulink model at a particular Level including the Subsystems from Third Party libraries. But In the result I get some values instead of names of the SubSystems from Libraries. Please could someone help ??

Instruction Used:

find_system('Level1/Level2','SearchDepth',1,'LookUnderMasks','on','BlockType','SubSystem')

Result:

```
'Level1/Subsystem1'
'Level1/SubSystem2'
[1x11 char]
[1x90 char]
[1x34 char]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find_system` method returns handles to simulink blocks. To get the name of the subsystem you have to use the `getfullname` function to get the names for the handles.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, i decided the read the .Mdl file itself rather than reading from Simulink model. Appreciate your quick Response though.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `find_system` returns a cell array or vector of handles, see the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/find_system.html):

> If `sys` is a pathname or cell array of pathnames, `find_system` returns a
>   cell array of pathnames of the objects it finds. If `sys` is a handle or
>   a vector of handles, `find_system` returns a vector of handles to the
>   objects that it finds. If `sys` is omitted, `find_system` searches all
>   loaded systems and returns a cell array of pathnames.

Use an output argument when calling the function and you'll be able to explore the contents of the returned variable, e.g.:

```
my_sys = find_system('Level1/Level2','SearchDepth',1,'LookUnderMasks','on','BlockType','SubSystem');
```

Then you should be able to see what's in `my_sys` and access its contents.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, i decided the read the .Mdl file itself rather than reading from Simulink model. Appreciate your quick Response though.

Comment: Never a good idea to read the `*.mdl` file directly, as the format is undocumented and changes from release to release, so what you are developing now probably won't work when using a different release.

Comment: Yes, I read the risk of doing the same in a couple of other sites aswell, But I understand that it should not be too difficult to accomodate the changes for other Versions.